# How to find the top column values of each row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

For a given dataframe with `m` columns (lets assume `m`=10), with in each row, I am trying to find top `n` column values (lets assume `n`=2). After finding these top `n` values for each row, I would like to assign the remaining column values, `m` - `n` in total, in the row to 0.

For an example, starting with the dataframe of values mentioned in the first table, I am trying to create a representation of first table with the filtering options discussed earlier. If more than `n` columns have same value, lower column index number is given preference

```
| col_A | col_B | col_C | col_D | col_E |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 0.1   | 0.1   | 0.3   | 0.4   | 0.5   |
| 0.06  | 0.1   | 0.1   | 0.1   | 0.01  |
| 0.24  | 0.24  | 0.24  | 0.24  | 0.24  |
| 0.20  | 0.25  | 0.30  | 0.12  | 0.02  |
```

```
| col_A | col_B | col_C | col_D | col_E |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 0     | 0     | 0     | 0.4   | 0.5   |
| 0     | 0.1   | 0.1   | 0     | 0     |
| 0.24  | 0.24  | 0     | 0     | 0     |
| 0     | 0.25  | 0.3   | 0     | 0     |
```

Is there any easier way to have this implementation. A vectorized format can help in dramatically reducing the processing time on large dataframes

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First idea is compare top N values per rows by [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and the nset values by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
N = 2
df = df.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.eq(x.nlargest(N)), axis=1), 0)
print (df)
   col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D  col_E
0   0.00   0.00    0.0    0.4    0.5
1   0.00   0.10    0.1    0.0    0.0
2   0.24   0.24    0.0    0.0    0.0
3   0.00   0.25    0.3    0.0    0.0
```

For increase perfromance is used `numpy`, solution from @Divakar:

```
N = 2
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/61518029/2901002
idx = np.argsort(-df.to_numpy(), kind='mergesort')[:,:N]
mask = np.zeros(df.shape, dtype=bool)
np.put_along_axis(mask, idx, True, axis=-1)
df = df.where(mask, 0)
print (df)
   col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D  col_E
0   0.00   0.00    0.0    0.4    0.5
1   0.00   0.10    0.1    0.0    0.0
2   0.24   0.24    0.0    0.0    0.0
3   0.00   0.25    0.3    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: This approach seems easy to understand. Is there any faster way to do it ?

Comment: @codecodercoding - answer was edited, Divakar solution help me with this a lot.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I can understand the logic used in the second code block. Thanks a lot for helping on this