# Top N values in 2d array with duplicates to mask

Tags: arrays, numpy, sorting, duplicates

I have 2d numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], 
                [0.06, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01], 
                [0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24], 
                [0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.12, 0.02]])
print (arr)
[[0.1  0.1  0.3  0.4  0.5 ]
 [0.06 0.1  0.1  0.1  0.01]
 [0.24 0.24 0.24 0.24 0.24]
 [0.2  0.25 0.3  0.12 0.02]]
```

I want filter top N values, so I use `argsort`:

```
N = 2
arr1 = np.argsort(-arr, kind='mergesort') < N
print (arr1)
[[False False False  True  True]
 [ True False False  True False] <- first top 2 are duplicates
 [ True  True False False False]
 [False  True  True False False]]
```

It working nice, at least not top duplicates, like for row 2.

Expected output:

```
print (arr1)
[[False False False  True  True]
 [False  True  True False False]
 [ True  True False False False]
 [False  True  True False False]]
```

Is possible some faster way for handle it?

Comment: Shouldnt that be `np.argsort(-arr, kind='mergesort')[:,:N]`?

Comment: Yeah the argsort gives us the top N indices in the order. So, slicing is needed. Then. use it to create a mask, I would say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slice to get those top N indices and use those to create the final mask -

```
idx = np.argsort(-arr, kind='mergesort')[:,:N]
mask = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=bool)
np.put_along_axis(mask, idx, True, axis=-1)
```